# Can you return the target of a with block from within the with block?

Tags: vb.net

It occurred to me that it would be handy if I could do this

```
With New MyObject
    .a = 5
    .b = 32
    .InitializationMethodA()
    'etc
    Return ???
End With
```

So it would be just another way of constructing an object. Ofcourse I could just do

```
Dim ret as New MyObject
With ret 
...
End With
Return ret
```

But if its possible to save those extra 2 lines worth of typing, I'm all for it. Is it possible?

Comment: From the little that is there, we cant see what you are returning *from*.  That first part wont compile because there is no object variable of MyObject is a type

Comment: Create code snippet for those - then you do not need typing extra lines.